# Chasing with mosquitoes

Tags: mosquitoes

Mosquitoes are the one of the most disliked <s>pets</s>pest, but they don't seem to take it to heart.

When I go fast through their territory, they seem to have problem with biting me (but if there are enough of them, they manage to do it), but they are circling around me and bite with joined force when I stop. Sometimes after I have to run a bit to get rid of them, but some are still chasing me.

I wonder if there are tests made, to check, what speed is necessary to:

1. Make it hard/impossible for mosquito to bite? Are the fast hand/leg movement more important factor than the core speed?
2. To leave mosquitoes behind, assuming they are willing to pursue you (if you go from shadows into full sun, they probably aren't)?

Comment: most disliked? So you don't have horse/deer flies where you live I presume

Comment: @KateGregory one of :)

Comment: Mosquitoes don't really persue as much as new ones swarm from all over. They are sensitive to changes in CO2 concentration caused by breathing from hundreds of meters away.

Comment: @crasic Hundreds of meters? Can you back that up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.mosquito.org/faq

> **How fast can mosquitoes fly?**
>
> Depending upon the species, mosquitoes can fly at about 1 to 1.5 miles per hour.

I got that source from [this recent article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/16/science/a-low-tech-mosquito-deterrent.html?_r=0) about using a fan to keep mosquitoes away.  It seems mosquitoes are slow fliers.  A normal walking pace should be enough to out run them.  That being said, you can still walk *into* other mosquitoes, and there are other, faster, flying insects.